# Get Array value from the complete callback in a Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a firefox extension. And for some odd reason when I make a ajax call the callback success (the results of success was the list I was looking for but not for complete) will not run, but complete will. With that said, on the server I am returning a array, which is transformed in json. If I must use the complete callback, can I get that list still? Thanks!

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType:'json',
            url: "http://api.com/data/album",
            complete: function (result) {//success not working
          //GET THE LIST RESULT HERE



            }
        });//End Ajax call to get albums
```

Comment: I'd add an error handler. Sounds like the request is erroring

Comment: Could you show us how exactly are you sending the array, and how are you trying to handle it?

Comment: Ok I will add that, should have been there in the first place. But surprised it would not work for FF ext but work for chrome.

Comment: @kilkadg I am returning a List<info> from the server. Works fine when testing.

Comment: If you do not write the code it is difficult to understand

Comment: I now see that it is bombing out, but now I cannot find a good error message to determine the issue. Debugging on FF extension is not an easy task. Any ideas on how  I can get a good error message. 

 error:function(x,y,z){
                console.log($.parseJSON(x.responseText));//not working
            },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

complete is called irrespective of success or error : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> A function to be called when the request finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed).

If success is not getting called and complete is , then error must be getting called and you need to check the cause of the error.